# Is CNN able to create new image with the help of sequence of input images?

Tags: python-3.x

My question is that whether the CNN is able to create a new image depending on the sequence of previous images. If it can do so can anyone give such as example. I have read this blog [CNN_from_scratch](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-a-cnn-from-scratch-for-cifar-10-photo-classification/) which explains good but has confusion in the implementation.
To simplify my question...... 
Let us take a swimmer swims in a pool and i have taken 10 photos of which the left hand of the swimmer rotates from forward to backward and right hand in the viceversa.
If i have sent these 10 photos as inputs to CNN. Will CNN can create the 11th image as output depending on these 10 photos specifications.

Comment: I think you are confusing CNN and RNN here. Also, I think the answer to your question is ... maybe? This entire topic is quite new, and very much being researched. I haven't heard of something like that yet, but that doesn't mean it isn't doable :) Just hard.

Comment: Yes, you are correct i am doing research on such a topic to attain faster prediction after NN has detected the images. Can anyone help in this sector or even a hint? Until now i have created few images of a cuboid aligned with quaternions. Now, i want to place these (t) images as input to CNN and i need (t+1)th image with new image of aligned cuboid. That's my overall task.

Comment: I think RNN is not much better in dealing with Images. Is that correct?

Comment: I think you need a lot to learn here. RNN is not *'this one network'*, it's a design principle. Sure, there are RNNs that are good for image processing, especially if you combine RNNs and CNNs. To give you a search direction, the technical term for what you are trying to do is **Video Extrapolation**. There are a couple of people that tried to tackle that subject, but so far, no one was really sucessful. Example: http://cs231n.stanford.edu/reports/2017/pdfs/714.pdf. Also, look at this list: https://paperswithcode.com/task/predict-future-video-frames/codeless

Comment: Thank you for that what you have sent. I have learnt many blogs, journals and books regarding this RNN. I knew that its a design to specify our model in  condition. The links that you have shared were good of which i have learnt similar pages before. As, you have said its clear with Video Extrapolation. If i have any doubt in further i will ask you. Thank you for your valuable time and helpful mind.